# Filtering solutions in PowerRepresentations

Tags: filtering, number-theory, number-representation, big-numbers, code

I have the following code:

```
PowersRepresentations[10400, 7, 2]
```

This produces `Length[PowersRepresentations[10400, 7, 2]]=433789` number of solutions. Now I want to filter in those solutions, the filter must remove the solutions when it does not exist of distinct integers (so for example $\left\{35, 35, 35, 36, 38, 41, 48\right\}$ must be removed because the number $35$ is used three times) and all the integers must be bigger than zero (so for example $\left\{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 100\right\}$ must be removed because the number $0$ is used and it is used five times). How do I code that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select[PowersRepresentations[10400, 7, 2], 
 DuplicateFreeQ[#] && ! MemberQ[#, 0] &]
```

Comment: Dear Flinty, I do not know if you want to but maybe we can combine forces for finding a magic square (I am not good at coding stuff but I know some things about Mathematics). So maybe it is a fun idea to work together on something. If you like that feel free to contact me at: jan.eerland1@gmail.com. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `IntegerPartitions`, which is faster than `PowersRepresentations`.

```
Select[IntegerPartitions[10400, {7}, Range[101]^2], DuplicateFreeQ[#]&]
```

or

```
Pick[#, Map[DuplicateFreeQ, #]]&[IntegerPartitions[10400, {7}, Range[101]^2]]
```

The maximum of the range, 101, is approximately the square root of the input integer 10400.